# A way to not repeat expressions in a SQL Server string manipulation query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have the following sql:

```
SUBSTRING(Location, 
          CHARINDEX(' : ', Location) + 3, 
          CHARINDEX(' ms - ', Location) - (CHARINDEX(' : ', Location) + 3))
```

(Location could be something like this:  `1dasev : 232 ms - 323-asv3R` and the `substring` would return `232`)

If I wrote this in C# I would not re-calculate `CHARINDEX(' : ', Location) + 3` twice.  I would store it in a variable, and then reuse it.

**Is there any cool trick in SQL to all me to do a similar thing?**  (My query will be more complex than the simple example above, and I am hoping to make it more readable.)

Comment: is the string format consistent?

Comment: you would have to introduce a sub query or a common table expression other than that nope so generally it is done by repeating the formulas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the trick is to use CROSS APPLY to calculate it

```
SELECT
SUBSTRING(Location, 
          c, 
          CHARINDEX(' ms - ', Location) - c)
FROM  YOURTABLE
      CROSS APPLY
      (
         SELECT c = CHARINDEX(' : ', Location) + 3
      ) c
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery to define your common expression:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Location, x.AfterColon, CHARINDEX(' ms - ', Location) - x.AfterColon)
FROM (
    SELECT *, (CHARINDEX(' : ', Location) + 3) AS AfterColon
    FROM ...
) x
```